# Get all products from english version - WooCommerce & WPML

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, wpml

I'm developing a web application that works with WordPress database. In my website,(which works with WooCommerce and WPML) I have products in two languages - english (1st), serbian(2nd). I wrote an SQL code that get the products from database, with their regular and sale prices and etc., but I want to get ONLY products where lang = en (the products from english version). The problem is I don't know how to get them.

Simple SQL:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE post_type = product';
```

This is the method that SELECT from database:

```
// SELECT
public function select (
            $table_1 = ' wp_posts ', 
            $table_2 = ' wp_postmeta ', 
            $rows = ' t1.id, t1.post_title, guid, post_type ', 
            $where = ' t1.post_status = "publish" AND t1.post_type = "product" OR t1.post_type = "product_variation" ', 
            $groupby = ' t1.ID, t1.post_title '
        ) {

    // Connect to database and set charset
    $this->connect();
    $this->conn->set_charset('utf8');


    // Published products
    $sql = "SELECT $rows,
            max(case when meta_key = '_regular_price' then t2.meta_value end) AS price, 
            max(case when meta_key = '_sale_price' then t2.meta_value end) AS sale,
            max(case when meta_key = 'attribute_colors' then t2.meta_value end) AS colors,
            max(case when meta_key = 'attribute_number' then t2.meta_value end)
            FROM $table_1 AS t1
            INNER JOIN $table_2 AS t2 ON ( t1.ID = t2.post_id ) 
            WHERE $where
            GROUP BY $groupby";

    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
    $published_products_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);



    // Trashed products
    $trashed_sql = "SELECT post_status FROM `wp_posts`
                    WHERE post_status = 'trash'";

    $trashed_result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $trashed_sql);
    $trashed_products_count = mysqli_num_rows($trashed_result);


    // If results -> show them
    if ($result) {

        printf( "\t\t" . "<p>There are <strong>%d published</strong> products and <strong>%d trashed</strong>.</p>", $published_products_count, $trashed_products_count);

    $table = '
    <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row. №</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Regular price</th>
                <th>Sale price</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>';

        $row_number = 1;

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $table .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $row_number++ . '</td>
                <td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.enroll.rs/wp-admin/post.php?post=' . $row["id"] . '&action=edit" target="_blank">' . $row["post_title"] . '</a></td>
                <td class="price">' . $row["price"] . '</td>
                <td class="sale">' . $row["sale"] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row["post_type"] . '</td>
                <td><a href="edit_form.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>';
        }

    $table .= '
    </table>';

        echo $table;
    }

    // If no results
    else {
        echo 'There isn't any products';
    }
}
```

I hope somebody help me!

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S. The application is not based on WordPress!

Comment: have you tried $sql = 'SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE post_type = product' AND language = 'en'; or you can also try $sql = 'SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE language IN('en') without seeing your sample output and table structure.

Comment: No, I have never tried with language = 'en' because in wp_posts table there isn't such column with name 'language'.

Comment: can you show ur table structure?

Comment: I just edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPML plugin creates several new tables to manage multilang, not affecting the standard WP posts tables. Specifically, it creates the  `wp_icl_translations` table, where it stores relations between posts and languages.

You need to add two new JOIN statements to your query:

```
JOIN wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id AND t.element_type = 'post_product' JOIN wp_icl_languages l ON t.language_code=l.code AND l.active=1
```

Then, you can add a new condition to your *WHERE* statement like this:

```
AND t.language_code='en'
```

Hope this helps.
Regards.